# Spring URL not changing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring.

In the index page, I have a jsp code like this:

```jsp
<a href="ja4s"><br> Click here to check the output :-)</a>
```

In the Controller, I have the following code:

```java
@RequestMapping("/ja4s")
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
    String msg =  "Welcome to Java4s.com Spring MVC 3.2.x                                          Sessions";

    msg += "<br>You Did it....!";

    return new ModelAndView("welcomePage", "welcomeMessage", msg);
}
```

In the `web.xml`, I have a URL pattern like this:

```xml
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

and when I try to run the project it is showing me an url like this

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram/
```

and when I click on the Link it is directing me to other page and shows a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram/ja4s
```

---

1. Now my doubt is when we are returning a model and view object in the controller
   we are getting getting redirected to **welcomepage** which is given by the model and view object in the controller.

but as my my understanding it should be like this

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram/welcomepage.
```

Instead it is showing me an URL like this

```
 http://localhost:8080/SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram/ja4s
```

2. When I change the url pattern in the `web.xml` like this

```xml
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern> <!-- It is giving me an error. -->
```

As per my understanding in the above URL pattern it should accept only pages ending with jsp (which I am providing), but am getting an error saying that the requested resource is not found in the server.

Can anyone help me with above two doubts? :)

Answer (score 0):

In simple explanation, 
The url

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram/ja4s
```

is the address or the path to the location of the resource (welcomepage.jsp) requested by the client (browser).

So you shouldn't be expecting to see

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram/welcomepage.jsp
```

That's the reason that bar is called an address bar and not a resource bar. The information on address bar is the address to the resource currently in view.